# Hosting vs DNS and domain management

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, reseller

I have the following problem.

I have a reseller hosting services which offer to my clients. One of my clients want to keep the domain and DNS management with him.

What information he needs to point "meucliente.com" for my resale?

Initially suggested the IP, where the client would configure the DNS type A record pointing to my IP. But I came across the following problem. My reseller has several websites, such as direct to the correct folder of the client?

My reseller is: www.premiumreseller.com

Comment: Not to be mean, but maybe this is a sign you shouldn't really be in the hosting business? :-/

Comment: @ceejayoz If you do not know the answer, do not need comments!

Comment: The answer is "you'll need to learn how to configure your web server". This is pretty basic stuff. Like it or not, you'll get comments on StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need to point their domains to the IP address of your hosting provider's webserver.

If you don't know what IP that is, you'll need to contact your hosting provider's support desk.

Comment: That's step one. For step two it'll depend what server software he's using. Apache would involve setting up VirtualHosts in the HTTPD conf, for example.

Comment: Since the OP is using a "reseller hosting" service, I made the (most likely correct) assumption that a cPanel-esque control panel is in play, in which case this would be take care of automatically.

Comment: Probably, yeah. Adding a second domain to an account is probably going to create a specific folder structure, though, so he's going to have to move stuff around if he already has it in a different structure. +1 for you, though.

Comment: Well, with cPanel at least, one can create "add-on domains" which are basically just additional NameVirtualHosts, that do automatically get their own folder as well. You're right, though, dude ought to know how to configure his own webserver, GUI or not.

Comment: When creating a new website for resale already creates the entire structure of folders.
http://i.imgur.com/Rvwo5.png  
Note that the IP is unique for all resale. The question is .. Only this IP is already sufficient for the customer to configure DNS in the "A" record pointing to this IP, and enter "datafilme.com.br" will be redirected to my resale in this specific folder?

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa - Most likely the IP is sufficient. How are we supposed to give you an authoritative answer, though? We can't possibly know how your hosting provider has things set up. Contact their support desk. That's what you pay them for.